# how to update multi select box using angular 1.5.7

Tags: angularjs

I have searched a lot for the issue which i am facing. I have just started learning Angular and stuck in this problem since 3 days and wasting my time to solve this.

i have roles listing array. i have added selected = true key value pair if that element is selected in the form.

```
     [{"role_id":1,"name":"MANAGER","selected":true},"role_id":2,"name":"USER","selected":true},{"role_id":3,"name":"Developer"}]
```

i have added selected roles in $scope.selectedRoles variable from controller and used in ng-model this way i can get selected role in edit form

```
<select ng-model="selectedRoles" multiple  ng-options="item.name for item in roles track by item.role_id" class="form-control" >                                   </select>
```

but when i save edit or add then i dont get any value in controller nor ng-model bind the input which i give in select

if i change ng-model to selectedRoles to permission.roles then i could save or edit.

i want to do both task which is not happening.
i appreciate in advance if any help.

Comment: Check the plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/q6uQbCXajZVaBUIPgKw6?p=preview

Comment: @Aparna. Your plunker makes no sense with what he's trying. First, he wants to select **multiple** items, also he's using `ngOptions` which is the **correct** directive for `<select>` tag, not `ngRepeat`. And @ Dnyanesh, your code is correct... Maybe there's something wrong in another place.

Comment: yeah it is correct when it is selected in edit form but when i am going to select another role or change role from list then it is not saving those fields .

Comment: Provide a plunker to demonstrate your issue then.

Comment: this one is working but not while edit. not getting selected option .  https://plnkr.co/edit/RVr0xiVFL2FW7pCv7zYj?p=preview

Comment: It really works.. I don't know what you're saying. Check it: [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/2qpUEP37jTJrHpU0KGa6?p=preview). Also, `ngValue` is completely unnecessary in this case, it makes nothing there.

Comment: i think some thing wrong with my back end code. anyways thanks for your precious time